# Different Results When Testing TLS Using CDN77

Tags: tls

I have enabled TLS1.3 on three servers that are behind another load balance server that has itself TLS1.3 enabled. I get different results if the domain name is written without www. All servers have active ssl certificates. Here are the test results when testing in cdn77 checker:

I get "Excellent" if www.waylisting.com is tested. However, 
I get "Poor" in Firefox and "Moderate" in Google Chrome if waylisting.com is tested without www.

I have no errors regarding ssl when testing in gmetrics, pingdom, and so on.
What am I missing in my configuration

Comment: Without access to the config file, this is impossible to answer. Even then, I would thing this is more a question for [sf].

Answer (score 2):

There is an inconsistent setup of the site. Currently a DNS lookup for the site returns 5 IP addresses and each DNS lookup returns these in a different order (i.e. DNS based load balancing), which means that multiple attempts to reach the site might actually reach different servers.

These servers seems to be configured differently. From [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=waylisting.com):

```
 172.104.210.88       Grade B
 172.104.22.58        unreachable
 45.79.155.107        Grade A+
 172.104.16.205       Grade A+
 172.104.219.176      Grade A+
```

And SSLLabs also adds a big warning

> Warning: Inconsistent server configuration

The [A+ grades](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=waylisting.com&s=45.79.155.107) are for servers which have TLS 1.3 enabled. The [grade B](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=waylisting.com&s=172.104.210.88) is for a server with no TLS 1.3, incomplete certificate chain and broken HSTS policy.

So it looks like that you've properly configured some systems but not others. Given that both www.waylisting.com and waylisting.com return the same 5 IP addresses but likely in different order it might happen that the testing can see different results for both domains, depending on which of the servers they actually end up testing.

Comment: And the same (addresses and results) for the www. version; the cert's SAN covers `waylisting.com *.waylisting.com`. SSLLabs also reports a redirect loop on the first address (which isn't strictly a TLS problem).

Comment: Thanks so much for helping. The problem was within the load balancing server for "server name" declaration. I had an extra server name that was not needed. Once removed CDN77 checker reports A+ for all servers, except the unreachable one because it is turned off and not fully configured yet. Again thank you for your diligence and patience. The issue is solved.